# using nsupdate to delete PTR record by hostname

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nsupdate

**nsupdate** allows to delete PTR record like this:

```
delete 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa PTR
```

How do I delete PTR record by hostname, something like

```
delete host.domain.com PTR
```

I've read man page, but it didn't help. An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nsupdate can't do that. The first parameter after "delete" is "name" of the record. You're trying to delete with "data" of the record.

You can scan the zone file, find matching records, add them to a file with a format that nsupdate understands and feed it to nsupdate.

Answer (score -2):

Here an example:

```
nsupdate -k keyfile << EOF
server yourserver
update delete 11.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
send
EOF
```

Comment: That's what's in the question.  Did you have anything new to add?